# Customize PrintDialog Window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, listbox, printdialog

In my WPF application, I am going to print the contents of my ListBox. I want to add a new control to the PrintDialog box to select the number of lines (items) to print.

Is it possible to customize the existing PrintDialog box and add a new control to bind to ListBox.Count?

Or is there a better way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Can you share with us the existing print dialog code with us ?

Comment: Why would anyone want to specify the number of lines to print? As opposed to say pages.

Comment: @RameshMuthiah, by "existing PrintDialog", I'm pretty sure he means `System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog` - so he wouldn't have any source code for that.  I'm guessing he means "I want to add", instead of "I added".

Comment: @Daniel.Thanks.You are right.I have edited the question.

Comment: @ Ryan Gates.Actually It is my project  requirements.In mY project I have customised listbox and height of the each item in the  list box is big in size.So it would be better to include "number of lines(items) to print" option.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually possible to extend common dialogs with .NET. I found [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996463.aspx). However, I'm not sure whether this also applies to the print dialog or whether it can still be done, but I suggest you read that first.

Answer (score 1):

"C# provides a standard PrintDialog which has all the basic print dialog functionality. Since it is declared as a sealed class, there is no way to extend it through C# native syntax."

Please see the following link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16797/Extending-C-PrintDialog-Part-I

You can always create your own "Printing dialog screen" from scratch , then you can add your drop down with the ammount of lines to print(dropdown) witch you then get from the listbox(concatenating or build string) and send to a specified printer.

Comment: actually   System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog is sealed System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog isn't!